# I want to copy all the tables, it's data, views and SP's from one oracle DB to another.. I am using 12C. Softwares are DB viewer and SQL developer

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I want to copy all the tables, it's data, views and SP's from one oracle DB to another.. I am using 12C. Software are DB viewer and SQL developer. Please note that I have tried twice on SQL developer but I am getting different errors.

Answer (score 3):

There are utilities designed for such a purpose.

Use **Data Pump** Export (in the source database) and Data Pump Import (in the target database). Note that you should have access to an Oracle directory (database object, owned by SYS, who grants you read/write privileges on it so that you could store DMP file into a filesystem directory located on the database server). Normally, DBA does that (creates a directory and grants you privileges).

Alternatively, if you use the ***original*** EXP/IMP utilities, you can store the DMP file onto your own PC - which is (obviously) simpler. Oracle discourages us to use those utilities (since 11g).

Here are [12c Database Utilities](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-original-export-utility.html#GUID-901CBBE0-65FB-439E-942D-F2038C18BCD2); on the left hand side you'll see the menu; read about utilities I've just mentioned.